# Same user/password no longer allows access to Ubuntu share from Windows 10

Tags: windows, samba, sharing

For years now I've had a stable setup serving files from an Ubuntu box to Windows 10 clients. By creating and using a Windows 10 user with the same username and password as the Linux file owner, I was able to share with no trouble, and had owner privs when using the share from the Windows side.

About 2 months ago (and I apologize for the vague timeline; other life events prevented me from digging in to the problem until now) I could no longer access the share from Windows. I don't try to access it every day, so I'm going to guess that a recent update to either the Windows or Ubuntu side was to blame.

If I chmod open permissions on files on the share from the Ubuntu side, I can access, read and write from Windows. It is this that makes me suspect a user problem rather than a more fundamental Samba problem.

There are of course lots of posts out there recommending the same user/pass as a good approach to the problem, but I'm not finding anyone who has my same problem in which that doesn't work.

I would like to return to the state I had before - only the correctly named user with password can access the share. I welcome any clues.

My Ubuntu box is running 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit, GNOME 3.36.8. Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, build 19041.985

Thanks.